# ActiveJDBC doesn't instrument Model when it contains forEach/lambda

Tags: activejdbc

After wasting a lot of time investigating why one of my Model classes was not instrumented anymore, I realized this line of code, from a static method I added to my Model, was the culprit:

```
// myObjects is a List<SomeModel>
myObjects.forEach((SomeModel m) -> System.out.println(m.getId()));
```

Why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might have stumbled on a bug. Please, file an issue here: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/issues and provide as much detail on how to reproduce as you can.